# I'm contracting from London for a company based in Paris, and they require Proof of Residence for my Ltd Company. Where can I get this?

Tags: united-kingdom, limited-liability-company

I've already gone through the process to obtain a "Proof of Residence" letter on the HMRC website.

Once the application was completed, the email I received stated about applications in general that if I was applying on behalf of:

> - a partnership or a Limited Liability Partnership (LLP), please apply in writing to the appropriate address in our guidance.
> - a Limited company, please apply in writing to the address which deals with the company's corporation tax liability.

My application was for the second. A Limited company.

What exactly does their bullet point mean? `the address which deals with the company's corporation tax liability`

Comment: I belive it means the address of HMRC office where your tax letters come form or the local office which deals with your tax matters(VAT is generally your local office and corporation tax is generally a centralized office).

Comment: @DumbCoder : I agree - could you turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DumbCoder mentioned in the comments, this will be a reference to the specific HMRC office that deals with your tax.

HMRC has a lot of offices around the country and it distributes responsibility for different taxpayers and different taxes around those offices. So once you know what your tax office is, it's best to use their address directly to get the most efficient communication.